# Reshaping Spark RDD - KV pairs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Is there a way to reshape a spark RDD in this manner. Essentially the opposite of this:
[Reshaping Spark RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085212/reshaping-spark-rdd)

Suppose I have:

```
[['id1', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4'], ['id2', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3']]
```

And want:

```
[['id1','v1'],
 ['id1','v2'],
 ['id1','v3'],
 ['id1','v4'],
 ['id2','v1'],
 ['id2','v2'],
 ['id2','v3']]
```

Noting that there are differing amounts of variables in each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ['id1', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4'],
    ['id2', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3']
])
rdd2 = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [[x[0], y] for y in x[1:]])
rdd2.collect()
>>>
[['id1', 'v1'],
 ['id1', 'v2'],
 ['id1', 'v3'],
 ['id1', 'v4'],
 ['id2', 'v1'],
 ['id2', 'v2'],
 ['id2', 'v3']]
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of how to correctly reference and loop through a subset of the list.